# Regex to validate CSV in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, validation, csv

Hi I am trying to validate a CSV sheet line by line .
The csv file contains :-

```
9,EditTest,expectedResult=nooptionsacltrue
10,AddTest,features={w;f;r}
1,AddTest,projectType=new,vtName=28HPM,status=ACTIVE,canOrder=Yes,expectedResult=duplicate
2,AddTest,projectType=old,vtName=28nm,status=ACTIVE,canOrder=Yes,expectedResult=invalidfeatures
```

Here is my code :-

```
    public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testdbcsv/ACL.csv"));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                String pattern = "^(\\d+),(\\w+),((\\w+)=(\\w+)),((\\w+)=(\\w+)+?";
                if(line.matches(pattern)){
                    System.out.println("pattern matched");
                }
//Code
}
```

But my regex seems incorrect .
Can anyone  please help me with the correct regex for the csv. Thanks .
Or is there any other way where I can validate my CSV according to a schema other than using regular expressions?

Comment: The given CSV should match for all the lines ?

Comment: Yes but is there a way to convert the csv to a xml and validate?>

Comment: The regex in my answer does the job.

Comment: Why do u want to convert it into an xml ?

Comment: So that it would be easy to validate an xml

Comment: If you know for sure that your csv would be in the format that you have provided, a regex should work fine with lesser code, rather than converting csv into an xml and then validating the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the validation for the second line should fail,

```
^(\\d),[A-Za-z]+(,[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$
```

**EDIT**

This should match all four lines in your given csv.

```
^(\\d)+,[A-Za-z]+(,[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9{};]+)+$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one    `"\\d+,\\w+(,\\w+=\\w+)+"`

Answer (score 1):

CsvValidator, A Java framework which validates any CSV files can used.

Check this url : http://mdshannan1.blogspot.in/2011/07/validating-csv-files.html